# Android close app on back button

Tags: android

The application looks something like this:
MainActivity -> UserActivity -> DetailsActivity. (approximate order of activities).

I would like to close the application when the back button is clicked in DetailsActivity (third activity in the row).

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Use action bar on click of app icon navigate to ap home screen click back button exit app. back button is used to navigate to previous activity. pls check this link http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to close activity even when the stack isn't empty, meaning there is more than 1 activity in stack?

Well if there is only one... just :

```
finish();
```

Otherwise the trick is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the same activity in `onCreate` :

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```

So you clear the stack and then kill the single one left... you can do this in any activity and of course use it in `onBackPressed` :)

Comment: finish() will end the current activity only!

Comment: Warlock read the entire answer please... :) this solution works... i know finish() ends the current activity but since you cleared the stack you only have 1 single activity ...your current one...

Comment: You don't need to do that manually! since android provides a direct call to move your activity to most bottom of the stack moveTaskToBack(true);

Comment: Warlock, the issue here was to EXIT the program on back press... if you reoerder the stack its still not empty...so once you use the back press button the activity from the top of the stack will be called...it still wont exit... what you need to do is clear the stack. otherwise you will just return to a different activity

Comment: @Jony-Y will clearing the stack affect other open applications as well?

Comment: clearing the stack will remove all the stacked activities from your current app... this will not effect any other applications, what it does is just remove the "application history" so you wont go back to previous activities... but this will not affect other applications

Comment: Does this solution really always work in given case (3 activities)? In the question there are 3 activities and if they are opened in this order: MainActivity -> UserActivity -> DetailsActivity, now if I will press back button I don't think the application will be closed. The app will go to UserActivity, then again if back button is pressed, it will go to Main Activity. Isn't it? This solution works perfectly for 2 activities though.

Comment: this solution will remove all past activities in the stack and so you can have 10..doesnt matter , you clear all stack and then you are only left with yours... so not a problem...havent tried @Ahmad Dwaik 'Warlock solution... but what I posted will work

Answer (score 20):

You can accomplish that by overriding the back button event
to add no history for specific activity on specific condition.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if ( ! getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(FROM_SETTINGS_KEY))
        moveTaskToBack(true); // exist app
    else
        finish();
}
```

in my example it check for a flag that is from where i had launched my activity, if launched from settings then act normally, else make it on top and exit app on back pressed

Comment: `moveTaskToBack(true);` is actually pretty neat, since that technically don't close the app but jumps out of it.

Comment: What is `FROM_SETTINGS_KEY`?

Comment: custom constant I defined

Comment: Nice. This is the behavior I'm looking for. This way, user can just dismiss the app without killing it when pressing back at login activity. So if user revisit the app, he/she don't need to relaunch the app all over again.

Comment: I do not understand `! getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(FROM_SETTINGS_KEY)` what are you checking for?

Answer (score 8):

Try this, Add `noHistory` in you mainifest file each and every activity.

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: If I put this in manifest, then in activity I just call finish() ?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I put noHistory in manifest for my activity and on back button pressed called finish, but I just got back to the previous activity

Comment: @John no need to call finish. Just put this onHistory thats enough

Comment: @MuraliGanesan what is op is in `UserActivity` and wants to navigate to previous activity?. check this use action bar http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: @John https://github.com/ihrupin/samples/tree/master/android/Close_All_Activities_Prj Here have sample project just download and use. You will get solution

Comment: @John you can try my answer with or without the condition

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you give you E-mail id.

Comment: @MuraliGanesan if you have a doubt ask here on stackoverflow itself.

Answer (score 7):

try this.

```
 quitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View paramView) 
  {
        finish();          
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

When you start UserActivity from MainActivity put finish() after startActivity(). 
do the same in  UserActivity  when you start DetailsActivity

Comment: Excellent!!! Works like a charm
And saves us from having to clear the stack when you want to close the app since each activity you nolonger intend to use can be closed as soon as you've navigated to the next activity in your workflow! :)

Answer (score 4):

Inside your current activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Inside MainActivity OnCreate:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [jony-Y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109602/7111561)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call UserActivity from MainActivity the call finish() after the startActivity().Below is the code:

```
Intent userActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
       userActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
       MainActivity.this.startActivity(userActivity );
       finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a file named Constants.java in the project

2) Add this code to that file

```
    public static void killAll() {

    for (Activity act : Constants.activity_stack) {
        act.finish();
    }
    Constants.activity_stack.clear();

}
```

3)Now when you are in Main Activity in onCreate() add the below snippet

```
        // add to stack
    Constants.activity_stack.add(this);
```

4)Similarly add User activity to the stack

5)In Delivery Details in onBackPressed() use the below snippet

```
Constants.killAll();//will kill all the activities and bring you out of the application.
```

Comment: It's better to let android handle activity life cycle, if you are done with some activity android knows what to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete class that shows how another activity is called when a button in the first activity is pressed.

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button goToSecondActivityButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRecommendationMessage)).setText("This is the first activity");

        goToSecondActivityButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_go_to_second_activity);
        goToSecondActivityButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

         goToSecondActivity();
    }

    private void goToSecondActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct but off topic since the OP is asking for how to "close" an application appropriately

Answer (score 1):

use **onBackPressed()** method in DetailedActivity

```
  override fun onBackPressed(){ //trigger when user press back button
      super.onBackPressed()
      finishAffinity()  //This will close all acitivities
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*on your activity*

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onBackPressed();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent a = new Intent(Qeydiyyat.this,Login.class);
    a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more ways to achieve this but here are 2 ways that works for me. One way would be to move the task back on the stack.

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Another way would be this:

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val activityToMove = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        activityToMove.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME) //Indicate the next activity
        activityToMove.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(activityToMove)
    }
```